# Can I place Outlook's mailbox and calendar on separate monitors?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Subject says it all. Is there a way in a multi-monitor setup, to place Outlook's calendar in one monitor and Outlook's mailbox in a different monitor?

I use Windows and MacOS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right-click Calendar from the toolbar bottom left. Choose 'Open in New Window'

[image]

Et voila, you can now move the calendar window to another monitor.

If you don't see the calendar icon next to the mailbox icon, click the `...` to edit the icons on the bar. From the dialogue box, re-arrange the list to move Calendar up (which is effectively to the left).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your sharing.